# Problemas com precisão de resultado

Tags: c#

Estou com um problema em que fiz um programa para calcular a média de um aluno, onde a condição é:

> MÉDIA =  NOTA1 + NOTA2/2 (o resultado deve ser >= 7 para o aluno ser aprovado)

O programa está rodando direitinho, o problema é que quando uso valores decimais próximo do 7 ele não retorna a resposta da condição...

Por exemplo; a média foi: *6,9*. O certo era aparecer a mensagem (REPROVADO), porém não aparece... se eu usar valores.

O mais curioso é que se for qualquer número decimal abaixo de 6, funciona normalmente... por exemplo:
media = 5,9 imprime REPROVADO com exito

```
string NomeDoAluno, disciplina, RA;
int NumeroDeFaltas;
double NP1, NP2, MEDIA_FINAL;


Console.Write("\nDIGITE O SEU NOME: "); 
NomeDoAluno = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("DIGITE O SEU RA: ");
RA = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("DIGITE A DISCIPLINA: ");
disciplina = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("DIGITE O SEU NÚMERO DE FALTAS: ");
NumeroDeFaltas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("DIGITE SUA NP1 E SUA NP2: ");
NP1 = Double.Parse (Console.ReadLine());
NP2 = Double.Parse (Console.ReadLine());

MEDIA_FINAL = (NP1 + NP2) / 2;


Console.WriteLine("\nNome:  {0} \tRA:  {1}", NomeDoAluno, RA);
Console.WriteLine("\nDisciplina: {0}   \t Número de Faltas:  {1}", disciplina,NumeroDeFaltas);
Console.WriteLine("\nNotas\tP1:  {0}  \tP2: {1}   \tMEDIA FINAL:  {2}", NP1, NP2,MEDIA_FINAL);

//CONDIÇÃO PARA APROVAÇÃO DO ALUNO 

if (MEDIA_FINAL >= 7 & NumeroDeFaltas <= 10)
{
    Console.Write("\nPARABÉNS VOCÊ FOI APROVADO !");
}


else if (NumeroDeFaltas > 10 & MEDIA_FINAL <= 6)
{
    Console.Write("\nVOCÊ FOI REPROVADO POR FALTA E NOTA!");
}

else if (NumeroDeFaltas > 10 & MEDIA_FINAL >=7)
{
    Console.Write("\nVOCÊ FOI REPROVADO POR FALTA !");
}

else if (MEDIA_FINAL <= 6 & NumeroDeFaltas <= 10) 
{
    Console.Write("\nVOCÊ FOI REPROVADO POR NOTA!");
}
```

Comment: else if (NumeroDeFaltas > 10 & MEDIA_FINAL < 7)  E TAMBEM  else if (MEDIA_FINAL < 7 & NumeroDeFaltas <= 10)

Comment: Pelo que eu vi, não tem nenhuma condição de reprova onde teste que é menor que 7, sempre menor que 6. Então valores entre 6 e 7 são ignorados dos testes.

Comment: A solução é dada pelo meu comentário acima, só elaborei uma resposta porque certamente outros farão baseados nessa condição.

Comment: leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

Você está misturando os tipos de dados para comparar(Int e double). O ideal seria que usasse apenas decimal ou double. 
Exemplos:

- 10 (Int)
- 10.0 (double)
- 10m (decimal)

  double MEDIA_FINAL = (NP1 + NP2) / 2.0;

Outro problema, é que as condições  não atendem o intervalo entre 6 e 7. O correto seria:

```
if (MEDIA_FINAL >= 7 & NumeroDeFaltas <= 10)
{
Console.Write("\nPARABÉNS VOCÊ FOI APROVADO !");
}

else if (NumeroDeFaltas > 10 & MEDIA_FINAL < 7)
{
Console.Write("\nVOCÊ FOI REPROVADO POR FALTA E NOTA!");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda ^^

Answer (score 1):

O intervalo menor que 7 não está definido, o sistema só está reprovando nota <= 6 quando deve ser < 7

```
else if (NumeroDeFaltas > 10 & MEDIA_FINAL < 7)

else if (MEDIA_FINAL < 7 & NumeroDeFaltas <= 10)
```

Assim cobre todas as combinações

```
if (MEDIA_FINAL >= 7 & NumeroDeFaltas <= 10)
{
Console.Write("\nPARABÉNS VOCÊ FOI APROVADO !");
}

else if (NumeroDeFaltas > 10 & MEDIA_FINAL < 7)
{
Console.Write("\nVOCÊ FOI REPROVADO POR FALTA E NOTA!");
}

else if (NumeroDeFaltas > 10 & MEDIA_FINAL >=7)
{
Console.Write("\nVOCÊ FOI REPROVADO POR FALTA !");
}

else if (MEDIA_FINAL < 7 & NumeroDeFaltas <= 10) 
{
Console.Write("\nVOCÊ FOI REPROVADO POR NOTA!");
}
```

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO ^^

Answer (score 1):

Certamente seu problema está na mistura dos tipos (`double`, `int`, etc) no calculo da media. Voce pode ler aqui sobre [qual a forma correta de usar float, double e decimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219211/float-double-e-decimal-qual-a-forma-correta-de-us%C3%A1-los).

Estava de bom humor, e resolvi escrever um codigo mais elaborado para fazer a mesma coisa, porém com orientação a objetos.

Divirta-se!

#### Calculando Media Like a Boss

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("\nDIGITE O SEU NOME: ");
        var nome = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("DIGITE O SEU RA: ");
        var ra = Console.ReadLine();

        var aluno = new Aluno(nome, ra);

        Console.Write("DIGITE A DISCIPLINA: ");
        var nomeDisciplina = Console.ReadLine();
        var disciplina = aluno.AdicionarDisciplina(nomeDisciplina);

        Console.Write("DIGITE O SEU NÚMERO DE FALTAS: ");
        var faltas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        disciplina.AdicionarFaltas(faltas);

        foreach (var prova in disciplina.Provas)
        {
            Console.Write("DIGITE A NOTA DA PROVA "+ prova.Tipo +": ");
            var nota = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            prova.DarNota(nota);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nNome:  {0} \tRA:  {1}", aluno.Nome, aluno.RA);
        Console.WriteLine("\nDisciplina: {0}   \t Número de Faltas:  {1}", disciplina.Nome, disciplina.Faltas);
        foreach (var prova in disciplina.Provas) Console.WriteLine("\nNotas\t{0}: {1}", prova.Tipo, prova.Nota);
        Console.WriteLine("\nMEDIA FINAL: {0}", disciplina.CalcularMedia());

        if (disciplina.AprovadoGeral())
            Console.Write("\nPARABÉNS VOCÊ FOI APROVADO !");
        else
        {
            if (!disciplina.AprovadoPorNota())
                Console.Write("\nOOPS! FOI REPROVADO POR NOTA!");
            if (!disciplina.AprovadoPorPresenca())
                Console.Write("\nOOPS! FOI REPROVADO POR FALTA!");
        }
    }
}

public class Aluno
{
    public string Nome { get; private set; }
    public string RA { get; private set; }
    public List<Disciplina> Disciplinas { get; }

    public Aluno(string nome, string ra)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        RA = ra;
        Disciplinas = new List<Disciplina>();
    }

    public Disciplina AdicionarDisciplina(string nomeDisciplina)
    {
        var disciplina = new Disciplina(nomeDisciplina);
        Disciplinas.Add(disciplina);
        return disciplina;
    }
}


public class Disciplina
{
    public string Nome { get; private set; }
    public int Faltas { get; private set; }
    public List<Prova> Provas { get; }

    private const int _faltasMaximasParaAprovar = 10;
    private const decimal _notaMinimaParaAprovar = 7m;

    public Disciplina(string nome)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Faltas = 0;
        Provas = new List<Prova>
        {
            new Prova(TipoProva.NP1),
            new Prova(TipoProva.NP2),
        };
    }

    public void AdicionarFaltas(int faltas)
    {
        Faltas += faltas;
    }

    public decimal CalcularMedia()
    {
        var total = 0m;
        foreach (var prova in Provas) total += prova.Nota;

        var media = total / Provas.Count;
        return media;
    }

    public bool AprovadoPorNota()
    {
        var media = CalcularMedia();
        return media >= _notaMinimaParaAprovar;
    }

    public bool AprovadoPorPresenca()
    {
        return Faltas <= _faltasMaximasParaAprovar;
    }

    public bool AprovadoGeral()
    {
        var aprovadoPorNota = AprovadoPorNota();
        var aprovadoPorPresenca = AprovadoPorPresenca();

        return aprovadoPorNota && aprovadoPorPresenca;
    }
}

public class Prova
{
    public TipoProva Tipo { get; }
    public decimal Nota { get; private set; }

    public Prova(TipoProva tipo)
    {
        Tipo = tipo;
    }

    public void DarNota(decimal nota)
    {
        Nota = nota;
    }
}

public enum TipoProva
{
    NP1,
    NP2
}
```

[Veja funcionando aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oFs0SF)

Comment: Resposta muito completa, você fez tudo de novo. kkkk

Comment: Essa afirmativa na pergunta "O mais curioso é que se for qualquer número decimal abaixo de 6, funciona normalmente... por exemplo: media = 5,9 imprime REPROVADO com exito" põe sua afirmação (Int e double) como improcedente.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não poderia ser uma questão de arredondamento do valor, seja para "cima" ou para "baixo" ?

Comment: Se for 6.1 e arredondar sem ser explícito, pode arredondar para 7.0 (pois é o próximo inteiro válido). Então, procede sim.

Comment: @JcSaint repare nos else if que não há nenhuma condição no intervalo maior que 6 até menor que 7. Esse é o problema, questão de lógica, quanto a questão do arredondamento nada posso afirmar pois não conheço a linguagem e nem sei como testar o código do autor da pergunta. Porém ele afirma que ""se for QUALQUER número decimal abaixo de 6, funciona normalmente", portanto deveria funcionar para qualquer numero abaixo de 7 se HOUVESSE na lógica condição de testar esses numeros abaixo de 7

Comment: Não sei nada de c# e nem sei como fazer seu netfiddle retornal algo, só sei que o autor afirma que "se for qualquer número decimal abaixo de 6, funciona normalmente..." e logo após afirma que  " ... por exemplo: media = 5,9 imprime REPROVADO com exito"

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO ...AJUDOU BASTANTE ^^

Comment: Vocês recomendam algum livro de criptografia para criptografar mensagens em c# ou c?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo abre o link, clica em "Run" e no rodapé estará o app rodando.

Comment: sim, isso já tinha feito, mas depois de clicar em "Run" não acontece mais nada, só pede para digitar um nome, digito um nome e não acontece nada!   Veja esse print http://kithomepage.com/sos/fiddle.png

Comment: Deu enter? Sei que é pergunta boba, mas...

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi pior que não foi boba não, hahaha, cara seu script  está excelente!